# Marking packets with iptables with a NAT

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, nat, qos

I have to write bash scripts for a router to control bandwidth limitation for a given user on a given domain name.

For this, I'm using iptables to mark the packets incoming from a restricted domain to a user ip address in the private network. With each couple user_ip/domain_ip I have a single key with which I can mark the packet.

I add those rules in the mangle table like this :

```
$iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d $userIp -s $restrictedDom -j MARK --set-mark $id 
$iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d $userIp -s $restrictedDom -j RETURN
```

My NAT setting in the nat table (eth0 is my internet interface, and I used tap0 for Lan interface) is

```
$iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

The packet for my Lan user should match a rule in the mangle table but is not catch.

Example : (table mangle in the PREROUTING CHAIN)
This is for example for marking packets coming from slashdot.org for the user 192.168.0.2 in the Lan network.

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 14858 packets, 7215129 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination      
 0        0 MARK       tcp  --  *      *       216.34.181.45        192.168.0.2         MARK xset 0x9/0xffffffff 
 0        0 RETURN     tcp  --  *      *       216.34.181.45        192.168.0.2
```

However, If I try to mark packets coming from slashdot.org on the internet interface of the router, the packets are catched, and if a computer in the Lan also consult slashdot.org, the same rule will mark them too.

So I guess there is a problem because of the NAT translation and I don't know exactly when to and in which order apply the rules.

In a first time, are my NAT settings good or incomplete in iptables ?
Did I miss an important thing about the rules or iptables concept ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you should use the **POSTROUTING** mangle table since you are marking the packets in the PREROUTING before the NAT engine.

Have a look at the IPTABLE Chain :

[image: IPTABLES CHAIN DRAWING]